# file read fails when memory is full

Tags: c++, c, linux, file-io

My file A.txt reside in particular directory and the size of this directory increases dymanically because some log files are saving there. Everytime I open and reads this file, but the problem is when Memory is full I am unable to open and read the file

Here I can't increase the size of memory. Can some one help by giving better Idea

Sorry for asking this generic question.

Comment: Please post some code and some ideas on how big these files are

Comment: Sounds like you're reading the entire file into memory, do you really need to do that?

Comment: Why not delete old log files so memory doesn't fill up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break your log file into pieces.  Save *separate* files in a hierarchically organized file system, and name them systematically too.  So if you previously had a single file for one day,

> log121022.txt

say,

instead create a folder `log120122` and within it store

> log12102201.txt, log12102202.txt, etc.

where now you're creating a separate file for each hour of the day.  The same principle applies breaking weeks or months into days etc.  Then within your program read from and write to just the smaller file you need.  To go through all of them you will need to write a loop whereas before you simply opened the file, but this extra code is not very complicated and obviously, spending a little time writing it is a lot better than constantly running out of memory.

Comment: Were it me, I'd want a punctuation character (dot or dash, probably) between the date portion and the number-within-day: `log120122-01.txt` (or even `log20120122-01.txt`; how soon we forget the lessons of Y2K). But I agree with the basic idea.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sure, I guess it wouldn't hurt to make the file names more human-readable.  But the read-in routine will of course be able to parse it equally well either way.  Right on 2012 vs. 12 though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
In my case log files are saving continuously in 2 mins time with time-stamp as file name and creation time is logged in A.txt. When the memory is filled with these log files I cant open A.txt to know the details.

Answer (score 3):

If the whole file won't fit in memory, don't slurp the whole file into memory; process it one line at a time.  Or get more memory.